# Org Roam Database Missing

Tags: org-mode, doom, org-roam

Running Doom Emacs 2.0.9 on Emacs 27.1.

I have in installation of org-roam with the following set-up:

```
(setq org-roam-directory "~/Documents/organize/org-mode")
```

FWIW, I use the same directory as my org directory:

```
(setq org-directory "~/Documents/organize/org-mode")
```

I have created a few notes with several backlinks and everything works as expected.

One thing is bothering me, though. There is no trace of the database needed to run roam.

Where should the roam database file be? In what name?

Comment: `org-roam-db-location` gives necessary db path.

Comment: @itirazimvar Thanks. That solved it. Please post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable which you are looking is `org-roam-db-location`

It's defined in `org-roam-db.el`

```
The full path to file where the Org-roam database is stored.

If this is non-nil, the Org-roam sqlite database is saved here.

It is the user's responsibility to set this correctly, especially
when used with multiple Org-roam instances.

References
References in org-roam-db.el:
(defcustom org-roam-db-location ...)   1 reference
(defun org-roam-db ...)                3 references
(defun org-roam-db-mark-dirty ...)     1 reference
(defun org-roam-db--initialized-p ...) 1 reference
(defun org-roam-db-clear ...)          1 reference
(defun org-roam-db-build-cache ...)    1 reference
```